# Group homomorphisms between $D_4$ and $Z_2 * Z_2$, and between $D_4$ and $Z_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Here $D_4$ is the group of symmetries of the square, with order 8. I'm not sure how to go about specifying homomorphisms between non-cyclic and cyclic groups.

Comment: Any homomorphism is determined by its value on any set of generators. In this case there are very few conjugacy classes in the targets, so it would be reasonably efficient to write down a pair of generators $r, s$ for $D_4$, and determine which assignments of $r, s$ to elements of the targets result in homomorphisms.

Comment: Is it possible for a map between $D_4$ and $Z_4$ to be surjective?

Comment: The method I mentioned exhausts all homomorphisms, and in particular, it will show whether a surjective homomorphism exists.

Comment: When checking the group homomorphism property, why does it suffice to only check the mappings of the generators of $D_4$?

Comment: The claim is any homomorphism is determined by its value on a generating set, but (1) not all mappings of generators result in homomorphisms, and (2) this does not mean one only needs to check the group homomorphism property for pairs of generators. Note, though, that in $D_4$, if $r$ is any reflection and $s$ is any element of order $4$, any element of $D_4$ can be written as $r^a s^b$ for some $a \in \{0,1\}$, $b \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$.

Answer (score 0):

One approach, assuming that you know that $D_4$ has the presentation
$$D_4 = \langle a,b\mid a^4 = b^2 = (ab)^2 = 1\rangle,$$
is to notice that the abelianisation $D_4/[D_4, D_4]$ is
$$\langle a, b\mid a^2 = b^2 = [a,b] = 1\rangle.$$
This is the group $\mathbb{Z}/2\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2$ and any homomorphism from $D_4$ to an abelian group must factor through the abelianisation.  In particular, there is a surjective homomorphism from $D_4$ to its abelianisation.  On the other hand, since the abelianisation has no element of order $4$, it follows that there can be no surjective homorphism onto $\mathbb{Z}/4$.